# How can I create a list of values for a field in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana to view data from Elasticsearch index. There is a field only has a few values. When I do search the field, how can I make the search bar as a `select` rather than a `free text input`? I know that there is a filter list like below image:

[image]

but it doesn't work for the case that top 5 values in 500 records have one value. How can I show all values in the history as a list for a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are looking for "controls" visualization.
[image]

Go to visualization > controls

Then choose option list, your index and your field.
The result will be a dropdown with values like if you did a select distinct on your field within the whole kibana range.

Add it to a dashboard to have a filtering interface human usable dashboard.
[image]

Update:
Maybe a simple filter on the discover page can answer to your question.
[image]

Comment: The visualization is not what I need. I am looking for searching logs not visualize the log. How can I search the log by dropdown list?

Comment: You can save a search in the discover pan. Then you'll be able to add it on the dashboard so it will react to your dropdown. But it's a little limited for a log use case. Please also note than with KQL in recent versions of kibana, you can benefit on autocompletion in the search bar, and you also have access to a dropdown list of results in the filters

Comment: The last screenshot is what I am looking for. Could you let me know how you create the dropdown list for the `category.keyword`? It shows as text input for me.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Just click on + Add filter, select your field in the drop down, the operator and clic in the value field, your drop down will appear. It's standard in recent Kibana

Comment: I am doing the same step but don't see it as dropdown. I am using Kibana 7.7.0. Is it not supported in this version?

Comment: It should work for keyword, but not with text datatype.

Comment: It's always a good practice to use keyword (and term query on it) to filter data. It you need to add it you can just add a multi field mapping on your field and execute an myindex/_update_by_query without any argument to fill the new field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html